# 'npm install websocket' dying on push

Tags: dotcloud

I am trying to setup a WebSocket example on dotcloud... but I can't get a WS library to install with NPM. Here is my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "wsdemo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "websocket": ""
    }
}
```

When I call **dotcloud push myappname** it errors saying that the websocket lib requires a newer version of Node to be installed. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the version number **1.0.6** to the version of websockets and it will work.

```
{
    "name": "wsdemo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "websocket": "1.0.6"
    }
}
```